# Image directory changes automatically in django 3.2 tenant schemas

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

I am working with Django Tenant Schemas. I have Image field in user model and i have used upload to function to store the avatars inside the /avatars/<tenant_name>/<user_id>/filename.

When i upload it uploads successfully but it stores inside the tenant folder by default and when i try to get it back it shows there is error.

**versions:**
django = 3.2
django-tenant-schemas = 1.11

my settings.py file.

```html
import os
from decouple import config

SHARED_APPS = [
    # created apps
    'tenant_schemas',
    'account',
    'org',

    # 'rest_framework.authtoken',
    # default apps
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
]

TENANT_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'portal'
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'tenant_schemas',
    'account',
    'org',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    # 'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'import_export',

    'portal'
]

DATABASE_ROUTERS = (
    'tenant_schemas.routers.TenantSyncRouter',
)

TENANT_MODEL = "account.Client"

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'tenant_schemas.storage.TenantFileSystemStorage'

PUBLIC_SCHEMA_NAME = 'public'

PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF = 'core.public_urls'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'account.tenantAuthentication.AuthenticationBackend']

SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ['auth.W004']

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'tenant_schemas.middleware.TenantMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core', 'templates')
BUILD = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR, BUILD],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build', 'media')

IMPORT_EXPORT_USE_TRANSACTIONS = True

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.User'

# Email Configuration
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_USERNAME')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER

# Celery
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
```

my models.py file

```html
import uuid
import os
from django.db import models
from tenant_schemas.models import TenantMixin


class Client(TenantMixin):

    def get_file_path(instance, filename):
        ext = filename.split(".")[-1]
        filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
        return os.path.join("images/logos/", filename)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    paid_until = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    on_trial = models.BooleanField()
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    need_self_registration = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path, null=True, blank=True)

    # default true, schema will be automatically created and synced when it is saved
    auto_create_schema = True
    auto_drop_schema = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.domain_url
```

I am attaching my screen shot images below.

my settings files [settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tBOR.png). [settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raveN.png). [Django admin page image url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R23MR.png). [file Directory in my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwbpF.png). [models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6mZE.png)

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: as per your instruction I have edited my question and added code for your reference. please help....